# How to select node in xpath?

Tags: html, xpath, codeception

I have video html tag like that:
`<video controls loop muted preload="metadata"></video>`
How to select video by using attribute like: controls, muted in xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this with `//video[@controls]` or even `//video[@controls,@muted]`. I can only recommend you to use an online tester, it really makes work easy. Check this one out for example: http://xpather.com.